# Where does ESXi decompress files to during install?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I just installed ESXi on a machine remotely. This machine had a few disks to pick from, and I didn't think about it at the time, but it didn't ask me where I wanted to install the OS to until after opening and decompressing the tarballs on the installation CD.

Did ESXi write to a disk to put those temp files? Was it all in RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory, simple as that.